# 401 (Unknown authentication scheme) when retrieving data for group-merbership

Tags: linkedin-api

I am getting a 401 (Unknown authentication scheme) problem when retrieving data for group-membership.

My application uses IN.API.Raw for retrieving the data but generates the error message as 401 (Unknown authentication scheme).

The response is shown below:

```
{
"errorCode": 0,
"message": "Access to group-memberships denied",
"requestId": "6YW0D6JWWR",
"status": 403,
"timestamp": 1395933151070
}
```

and the JS code is below for the group-memberships.

```
IN.API.Raw("/people/~/group-memberships?count=100&start=0")
.result(function(result) {
jQuery('#ligroupslabel').html("<strong>To edit the group, simply choose from your list of groups below:</strong>");
for (var i = 0; i < result._total; i++) {
jQuery('#linkedInGroups ul').append(
"<li><a href=\"linkedin_connection\" onclick=\"saveGroup('" + result.values[i].group.id + "','" + result.values[i].group.name + "'); return false;\">" +
result.values[i].group.name + "</a></li>");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 = Your request may be alright, but there is the little problem of authentication. You have to provide some proof of who you are. You would usually have a header which gives an authentication scheme and some authentication information in the request.

You may not have supplied any authentication scheme at all; quite possible that you get the (not entirely accurate) error message "unknown authentication scheme" in that case.

Comment: you have mentioned "You have to provide some proof of who you are", what kind information needed to give, can you elaborate it please.